# Building web services in 2012. What SOAP version to choose?

Tags: web-services, soap, interop, wsdl, version

Most web service tools support both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 but what should be the version to choose when building a new WS?

I'm thinking WSDL 2 wasn't really all that adopted, but is that the case for SOAP also? Is SOAP 1.1 still considered the "de facto" standard when building SOAP web services or should SOAP 1.2 be used?

Comment: I would say that in many cases the best version of SOAP, is no version.  For the most common web applications, SOAP is over complicated.

Comment: @mikerobi he may have to use SOAP for technical interoperability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the technology you're using permits it, then expose endpoints with both versions of SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP 1.2 is a bit easier to handle. For example, you don't have to add the `SOAPAction` header to the request when using SOAP 1.2. The article below has a bit about it.
[Request Differences SOAP 1.1, 1.2](http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-Request-Differences-SOAP-1-1-and-1-2.html)

The main thing you should check is to confirm that any prospective consumers you will have for your services will be able to consume 1.2. On a side note, if you want to ensure maximum interoperability, try and ensure that you can generate good concrete WSDLs for your services. Avoid included WSDLs, included XSDs as much as you can.
Tools like XMLSpy, SoapUI etc are going to have no issue with 1.1 or 1.2 and included XSDs, WSDLs.